# RightJs lightbox doesnt show long texts

Tags: lightbox, rightjs

I have a webpage that I want to pop-up a description in it. I've used rightJS light box 2.4.0. It works fine but the only problem is that it just shows a portion of my text. I have attached a sample file to check; As you can see it doesn't pop-up the whole text.

Any suggestions?

thanks

this is a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RightJS: Lightbox</title>
 <script src="right.js"></script>
 <script src="lightbox.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="lower">
<a href onclick="Lightbox.show($(&quot;loremm-block&quot;).html()).resize({width:&quot;20em&quot;}); return false;">Link</a>
</div>

<div id="loremm-block" style="display:none;"> a very long text </div> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect Lightbox DOM via inspector in Chrome or Firefox you will see that it actually has the whole text inside the Lightbox but **rui-lightbox-scroller** has

```
overflow:hidden
```

CSS rule and it cuts off the text.

Play with width settings of Lightbox or try applying the following CSS rule to this element (**rui-lightbox-scroller**):

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

The HTML structure is described in **Style adjustments** section where you can compare the DOM